# Facebook Ads API Invalid Parameter issue ADGROUP_STATUS

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create an ad using the Facebook Ads API. So far I've already created the Ad Set, Ad Creative and Campaign.  But, when I use the following code to create an ad, I'm receiving `Invalid Parameter exception`. What, if any, error have I made in the following code?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message 'Invalid parameter'
  in /..../fbsdk/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php:137
  Stack trace:
    #0 /...../fbsdk/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Client.php(216): FacebookAds\Http\Exception\RequestException::create(Array, 500)
    #1 /..../fbsdk/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Request.php(282): FacebookAds\Http\Client->sendRequest(Object(FacebookAds\Http\Request))
    #2 /..../fbsdk/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Api.php(152): FacebookAds\Http\Request->execute()
    #3 /..../fbsdk/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Api.php(194): FacebookAds\Api->executeRequest(Object(FacebookAds\Http\Request))
    #4 /home1/d2 in /..../fbsdk/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php on line 137
Your ads couldn't be created for the following reason: You must include the required field "adgroup_status"
```

I have tried by adding this:

```
AdFields::STATUS => Ad::STATUS_PAUSED
or this
AdFields::ADGROUP_STATUS => AdGroup::STATUS_PAUSED,
```

but it did not work.

```
$ad->setData(array(
  AdFields::CREATIVE =>
    array('creative_id' => $creative->id),
  //AdFields::STATUS => Ad::STATUS_PAUSED, // try this but<-- this is ainvalid FB SDK 2.5.0
  AdFields::NAME => 'My First Ad',
  AdFields::ADSET_ID => $adset->id,
));
```

Comment: $ad = new Ad(null, $account->id);
$ad->setData(array(
  AdFields::CREATIVE =>
    array('creative_id' => $creative->id),
  //AdFields::STATUS => Ad::STATUS_PAUSED,
  //AdFields::ADGROUP_STATUS => AdGroup::STATUS_PAUSED,
  AdFields::NAME => 'My First Ad',
  AdFields::ADSET_ID => $adset->id,
));
$ad->create(array(
  Ad::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Ad::STATUS_PAUSED,
));
echo 'Ad ID:' . $ad->id . "\n";

Comment: don't add code in comment, rather add it in question by editing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed minor English issues and marked up the first mention of the error by using accents ``

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report for this issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/434655563408601/

**Bug report:**

> The POST endpoint for act_ID/ads is still expecting the
>   "adgroup_status" parameter, when it should be "status" since API v2.5

**Response from Facebook:**

> We have managed to reproduce this issue and it appears to be a valid
>   bug. We are assigning this to the appropriate team.

As far as I know it is currently not possible to create an Ad using the v2.5 Ad SDK, because the adgroup_status parameter is required but at the same time deprecated.

Comment: Any update on this? I've been trying to create an ad using Ad SDK but you are saying it isn't possible???

Comment: Creating ads is definitely possible now. This post was about SDK v2.5 when it was freshly released. The bug has been solved a long time ago. You should be using SDK v2.8 or v2.9 at this point anyway.